# Simple work done question I did it but the answer not matching

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

An object moves along a certain path from point A with position vector $r_1 = 2i + 3j$ to point B with the position vector $r_2  = 3i - 2j$ under the Force $F = i +j$. Find out the work done by the force

**What I  did**

$$W = F* S
  = (i+j)(r_2-r_1)
  =(i+j)(3i - 2j - 2i -3j)
  = -4$$

**Answer sheet: 0**

Comment: I got $-4$ but that is only a matter of orientation. The two position vectors are perpendicular. You get the result $0$ if one is the force and the other the path. Are you sure you didn't mess up the problem statement?

Comment: @MariusS.L. I am sure I didn't mess up with the question.

Comment: Then $0$ is the wrong answer. Maybe the author confused the directions.

Comment: Here is what I did. I took the path $\gamma : [0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined as $\gamma(t)=(2,3)+t(1,-5)$ and integrated $W=\int_0^1 F(\gamma(t))d\gamma(t)=\int_0^1 (1,1)\cdot (1,-5) dt =\int_0^1 (-4)dt=-4.$

Comment: It may be. Btw Thanks for your answer @MariusS.L.

Comment: Another possibility is a simple typo. We also get $0$ in case $F=5i+j$

Comment: Or if $r_2 = (3\mathbf i + 2\mathbf j),$ a single sign change.

Comment: @MariusS.L. My friend found the magnitude | r1 | = sqrt (13),  |r2| = sqrt ( 13) and then subtracted r2 from r1 and the answer was matched. is this legal

Comment: @AmritPant This only says that both position vectors are equally long. It doesn't help. You have to multiply force and path somehow, as you did or per integral. I like David K's explanation: sign error. This is more likely than messed up directions, or confusion about what vector is what,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the correct answer is $W=-4$.

For easier computation, note that $W_{total}=W_i+W_j$

The general equation for $Work$:
$$W=F*l$$

We calculate $W_1$:

$$W_i = F_i*(r_{2i}-r_{1i})=1*(3-2)=1*1=1$$

Now $W_2$:

$$W_j = F_j*(r_{2j}-r_{1j})=1*(-2-3)=1*(-5)=1$$

So

$W_{total}=W_i+W_j= 1-5=-4$